# Adding a format method to a string in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, html

For an assignment, I'm supposed to add a new method to a string that formats the string so that it has a color, typeface (italic, bold, etc.), font size, and all uppercase or lowercase letters.

So, I'm supposed to make the string "Jose lived in San Jose for many years." formatted so that it is blue, italic, size 12, and all uppercase. I'm having trouble getting started on this, so any pointers?

Comment: It will help if you post the code you have at this point so we know exactly how we need to communicate a solution, unless you don't have any code / don't know where to start

Answer (score 3):

You can add a method to a type `T` using `T.prototype`, like so:

```
T.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert('It did something!');
};

new T().doSomething(); // It did something!
```

And the same applies for strings. You can refer to the current object using `this`, which, like any other string, can be concatenated with strings... maybe some HTML to wrap your string, containing inline CSS to style it? (Or better, CSS classes - but that doesn't sound like the assignment.)

I hope that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Formatting text in JavaScript](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/formatting-text-JavaScript.asp). If your goal is literally a "new method" that does this formatting, then you can wrap all of these string formatting commands into a function. It sounds like the lesson is to abstract all of this logic into a callable function, so:

```
function FormatMe(str)
{
str = str.bold;
//etc.,etc.
return str
}
```

I can give more concrete examples if needed.